# What is the most obfuscated, inefficient and most challenging to understand method for checking to see if a number is even?

Tags: algorithm, performance, architecture

I've recently seen some fairly poor attempts at trying to detect if a number is even, and it's made me wonder, just how bad can this get? What's the worst possible implementation / algorithm (is there such a thing as a worst in this case?)

Comment: Attempt to divide each number X into every odd number between 3 and X-1, and see whether the final result is 1.  Of course, one would have to make sure none of the numbers used for trial division were even, but since one would only need to check numbers up to X-1, one could test each of those recursively.

Comment: Generate a list of all the prime numbers from 3 to your N using a very inefficient and obfuscated method.  Then generate a second list of all the prime numbers 3 to N using a different inefficient and obfuscated method.  Then calculate the sums of all possible pairs, one from each list.  If your N matches one of the pair sums or is 2 or is 4 then it is even.  Naturally, you only test for 2 or 4 at the end.

Comment: @rossum Great solution. But AFAIK, this require the Goldbach conjecture to be true, which is not yet proven although no one has yet shown that it is wrong (and AFAIK all 32-bits numbers have been already tested). This also makes the solution pretty vicious and so interesting!

Comment: @blueberryfields there is no worst case: you can design a simple algorithm to do that written in a custom language and use an interpreter to execute it. The interpreter can itself be interpreted recursively. More that 5 level of recursive interpreter are often enough to introduce a x1000000 overhead (especially if the interpreter are not optimized). The Python JIT PyPy can do that since PyPy is written in (restricted) Python and so the JIT can be interpreted by itself or the CPython interpreter. Running PyPy with CPython is insanely slow, even for simple/fast Python codes.

Comment: The Goldbach conjecture has been tested to some very large numbers, so the method depends on the value of the selected number.  That is N <= [400,000,000,000,000](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Goldbach_Conjecture) (or possibly more by now).

Comment: @JérômeRichard that sounds like a feature, not a bug

Answer (score 0):

For the programmer with numerical analysis background, the most obvious is

```
bool is_even(unsigned n) {
    int sum = 0;
    int addend = 1;

    while (n > 0) {
        sum += addend;
        addend = -addend;
        n -= 1;
    }

    return sum == 0;
}
```

It could be sufficiently worsened by summing up an alternating harmonic series (as `BigFraction`s) and comparing the result to `ln 2`. To be robust, the comparison phase needs some ingenious math. In fact, any converging alternating series would do.

A much more computationally involved approach is to compute Riemann's zeta. For even `n` we know [what it should be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values). Good luck.

I am sure there are even <strike>better</strike> worse solutions.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Worst implementation?

- Write every number in existence into 2 flat files (using the heaviest XML possible, of course) - 1 file has odd numbers, the other has even.
- Encrypt files using some home-grown half-arsed crypto which is both weak and slow.
- Locate files on a different server from where your logic is running.

At runtime:

- Pull the even numbers file across the network.
- Decrypt it.
- Load the even file into memory for use.
- Do a for-each loop over every number and see if it matches the input number.
- If it does, make a note of that.
- Keep iterating through to the end of every even number in existence - just in case.
- Purge even number data from memory - you don't want to use it again in case the source file gets updated with different even numbers.

Optional: do same process on the odd numbers, just to make sure it's not an even and odd number.

If the method works, return true/false; for all other cases, including errors, just return null, and be sure not to log any error data, etc.

Assumption - you only care about integers, not decimals, floats, doubles, etc.